# Docx4j trying to apply template to document

Tags: java, docx4j

Im trying to attach the templates header, footer and styles to a docx documents from a dotx, but docx4j only applies the styles and ignores the header and footer. Am i doing something wrong? Is there a way to do this?

````
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(bindClass);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            marshaller.marshal(bindingInstance, writer);
            String inputXML = writer.toString();
            System.out.println(inputXML);
            // Load input_template
            
            WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = Docx4J.load(getDocx("doc.docx"));
            
            wordMLPackage.attachTemplate(getDotx("template.dotx").getAbsolutePath());
            
            Docx4J.bind(wordMLPackage, inputXML, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_XML);

            Docx4J.save(wordMLPackage, bos, Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_BIND_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_INSERT_XML | Docx4J.FLAG_BIND_REMOVE_XML);

            System.out.println("DocumentPrintHandler.bindData() ==>" + wordMLPackage.getDocPropsExtendedPart().getContents().getPages()); //$NON-NLS-1$
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            Logging.i("DocumentPrintHandler.bindData() (JAXBException)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return null;
        } catch (Docx4JException e) {
            Logging.i("DocumentPrintHandler.bindData() (Docx4JException)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logging.i("DocumentPrintHandler.bindData() (Exception)", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
            return null;
        }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }```
````

Comment: attachTemplate only sets the relevant property in DocumentSettingsPart.  If you want to copy the headers/footers over, you'd need code to do that.  https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/copy-header-from-a-docx-file-to-use-in-other-while-creation-t2449.html contains some code to do that, but won't do it recursively (eg to copy images).  I'll write some code for this over the holiday period.

Comment: Great, but my header and footer have images in them.